# Условие в MODX REVO

Tags: modx

Здравствуйте! Имеется MODX REVO 2.3.1. Нужно кое-что поправить на сайте, но никогда не работал с данной системой. Открываю ресурс «Личный кабинет» и вижу там такой код:

```
[[!officeProfile?&tplProfile=`[[!pdoUsers:is=`name_B`:then=`tpl.Office.profile.form2`:else=`tpl.Office.profile.form`?&tpl=`@INLINE [[+extended.status]]`&users=`[[+modx.user.id]]`]]`]]
```

Насколько я понял, то в этом условии выбирается нужный шаблон (если name_B, то шабон form2, а во всех остальных случаях — шаблон form).

Задача состоит вот чем: нужно изменить условие так, чтобы для name_A — выбирался шаблон form1; для name_B — form2; для name_C — form3; для name_D — form4 и для name_E — form5.

Подскажите, как лучше это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы не составлять очень длинную конструкцию из вложенных модификаторов

```
:is=``:then=``:else=`[[:is=``:then=``:else=`[[...]]`]]`
```

лучше всего создать сниппет, например, getTplProfileForm со следующим содержимым:

```
<?php

$output = '';

switch($scriptProperties['name']) {    
    case 'name_A':        
    $output = 'form1';
    break;
    case 'name_B':        
    $output = 'form2';
    break;
    case 'name_C':        
    $output = 'form3';
    break;
    case 'name_D':        
    $output = 'form4';
    break;
    case 'name_E':        
    $output = 'form5';
    break;
}

return $output;
```

После этого первоначальный код можно будет заменить следующим:

```
[[!officeProfile?&tplProfile=`[[!getTplProfileForm?&name=`[[!pdoUsers]]`]]`?&tpl=`@INLINE [[+extended.status]]`&users=`[[+modx.user.id]]`]]`]]
```